# Deployed WAR from STS (Spring Tool Suite) 3 on Jboss returning 404

Tags: java, spring-boot, jboss, spring-tool-suite, jboss-eap-7

I'm trying to deploy a spring boot app into jboss using STS with the JBoss tools plugin.

The application runs fine if I run it as "Spring Boot App", but it returns 404 when  I run it as "Server" on a Red Hat 7.2 using the EAP 7.2 with JBoss tolls on STS.

The version of STS I'm using is 3.9.8.RELEASE
The version of the JBoss Tools plugin is 3.10.2.v20181101-1129

This is my POM file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-rest-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

This is the override for the SpringApplicationBuilder:

```
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

public class SpringInitializer  extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }
}
```

This is my Controller class:

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class GreetingController {

    private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";
    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="World") String name) {
        return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(),
                            String.format(template, name));
    }
}
```

And this is the main class:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

And this is the greeting class....just in case:

```
public class Greeting {

    private final long id;
    private final String content;

    public Greeting(long id, String content) {
        this.id = id;
        this.content = content;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }
}
```

If I right click on the project explorer, run as Spring Boot App, the application returns the right response when called like this:

http://localhost:8080/greeting

[Response when running as Spring Boot App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DauhH.png)

but if I deploy it to Jboss it returns 404.

When I run it as Server, the logs return this:

```
17:48:15,176 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 9) Inicializando Mojarra 2.3.5.SP2-redhat-00001 para el contexto '/gs-rest-service-0.1.0'
17:48:15,590 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 9) WFLYUT0021: Contexto de Web registrado: '/gs-rest-service-0.1.0' para el servidor 'default-server'
17:48:15,609 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYSRV0010: Implementado "gs-rest-service-0.1.0.war" (runtime-name : "gs-rest-service-0.1.0.war")
```

Which I assume, changes my context to:
http://localhost:8080/gs-rest-service-0.1.0/greeting

[Response when running as Server on Jboss 7.2 EAP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzEpH.png)

Answer (score 0):

There are some steps you need to do when you want to deploy format change from jar to war.

**1. You need to make your main method extends "SpringBootServletInitializer".**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}

@Override 
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) { 
    return builder.sources(SpringBootSampleApplication.class); 
}
```

Please check the newly implemented **"configure"** method.

**2. Change the scope of embed servlet.**

Once you start using war, **you don't need to use default tomcat in springboot**.
Open your pom.xml file and change & add this content.

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId> 
    <scope>provided</scope> 
</dependency>
```

You need to check **"scope" is set "provided"**.

**3. Package in "war".**

Finally, you need to package your application in war file.
Please open your pom.xml and change or add **"packaging"** value.

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

I hope my answer will help you.
Have a nice day & coding!

Comment: Please also check here: 
https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-deploy-war-file-to-tomcat/

Comment: Hi Yongsoo, thanks for your answer. Both the dependency and the extended class on my code were already implemented, as well as the packaging for the WAR. I'm going to give it a try with the link you are sharng and let you know how it goes.
Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

While deploying the spring boot war file in JBoss EAP you need to take care of few things like below.

You need to create jboss-deployment-structure.xml file inside src/main/webapp/WEB-INF folder.

```
    <jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment> 
        <exclude-subsystems>
            <subsystem name="jpa" />
        </exclude-subsystems>
         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example.com</groupId>
    <artifactId>projectname</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>projectname</name>
    <description>description</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId> 
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin> 
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.jboss.logging" /> 
            <module name="javaee.api" /> 
        </exclusions>  
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

After that create jboss-web.xml file in directory src/main/webapp/WEB-INF as mentioned below.

```
<jboss-web>
     <context-root>appname</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

After doing these changes build the project using "mvn clean install" and them locate the war file in the target folder and deploy that war file on JBoss EAP.

Try to access the deployed war file using URL below, don't give the snapshot and version in the context.

http://localhost:8080/gs-rest-service/greeting

I hope this will help.